# SWIFT 4 UISearchBar and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I started a table view with a list of universities and created a search bar to tag along with it. The search bar works but only if I type in the name of the school exactly how it is. Is there a way I can change the it to search any part of the name and get the same results? Here's the code that I have set up.

```
@IBOutlet weak var schoolSearch: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

let schoolnames = ["Long Beach City College LAC", "California State University, Bakersfield", ...]

var searchedSchool = [String]()
var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    schoolSearch.delegate = self

    self.tblView.delegate = self
    self.tblView.reloadData()
}

extension ChooseSchool: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchedSchool.count
        } else {
            return schoolnames.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
        cell?.img.image = UIImage(named: schoolnames[indexPath.row])
        cell?.lbl.text = schoolnames[indexPath.row]

        _ = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        if searching {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = searchedSchool[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = schoolnames[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestController") as? TestController
        vc?.schoolnames = schoolnames[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchedSchool = schoolnames.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        searching = true
        tblView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tblView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
searchedSchool = schoolnames.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
```

with

```
searchedSchool = schoolnames.filter { $0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make your searchBar implement the containsString method to achieve what you need. For reference look at this [link](https://medium.com/@satindersingh71/uisearchcontroller-with-scope-filter-8195f6a11eff)

Comment: Consider adding some relevant code-reference to your answer rather than just a mere link for they are subjected to change.